# libusb returns zero devices on Cocoa App

Tags: macos, libusb

To reproduce:
Clone libusb from github, open the project inside the Xcode folder, add a Cocoa target, add the libusb static library target as dependency and linked library, and run with these lines in viewDidLoad

```
libusb_init(NULL);
libusb_device** list;
long res = libusb_get_device_list(NULL, &list);
```

`res` will be zero. However, if the above is repeated for a "Command Line Tool" target, it will be at least 2 depending on your mac and the number of USB devices connected to it.
What is happening here?

Comment: I tried it but it is always 0 for me. | I downloaded the code, added the targets, all looks good but nada.. maybe because libusbb doesnt work with usb-c or so... anyway ...

Comment: maybe on mac use IOKit instead... sorry no idea.

Comment: will take a look now...

Answer (score 0):

Not a libusb bug. The following libusb issue shows how to get it working. This would be needed even if you used IOKit directly.

https://github.com/libusb/libusb/issues/463#issuecomment-420134260